# Continue case in switch

Tags: php, switch-statement, continue

I have following code:

```
switch(true)
    {
    case (something):
        {
        break;
        }
    case (something2):
        {
        break;
        }
    case (something3):
        {
        break;
        }
    }
```

Also the `switch` statement must check what one of cases give a `TRUE`, that is not the problem, the problem is, that i have now a case, where inside of `case ... break;` after checking other data, i wish to choose other `switch-case`, the one, that following him.
I have try do this:

```
switch(true)
    {
    case (something):
        {
        break;
        }
    case (something2):
        {
        if(check)
            {
            something3 = true;
            continue;
            }
        break;
        }
    case (something3):
        {
        break;
        }
    }
```

But PHP do not wish to go in to the `case (something3):` its break the full `switch` statement. How i can pass the rest of code of one case and jump to the next?

Comment: Will `something3` always be after `something2`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your code:

```
switch(true) 
{
    case (something):
    {
        break;
    }
    case (something2):
    {
        if(check) {
            something3 = true;
        }
        else {
            break;
        }
    } 
    case (something3):
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

This will get to case something2 and run your check.  If your check passes then it doesn't run the break statement which allows the switch to "fall through" and also do something3.

Answer (score 6):

This is what's called  a "fall-through". Try organizing your code with this concept.

```
switch (foo) {
  // fall case 1 through 2
  case 1:
  case 2:
    // something runs for case 1 and 2
    break;
  case 3:
    // something runs for case 3
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
case (something2):
    {
    if(!check)
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
switch(true) {
    case (something):
    {
        break;
    {
    case (something2):
    {
        if (!check) {
            break;
        }
    }
    case (something3):
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had some similar situation and I came up with a solution which in your case would be like this:

```
switch(true)
{
    case (something):
    {
        break;
    }
    case (something2):
    {
        if(!check)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    case (something3):
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

You see that instead of checking the conditions to go to the next case, we checked if we should ignore the current one.